# Qt & PHP: File upload with additional key

Tags: php, qt, post, upload

I have managed to get my code for a file upload script to my server working.
It is a pretty stupid piece of code that currently accepts every file.
That means, everyone accessing the script could instantly upload files.

Here is my current PHP code, which will receive the POST data and handle the request:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
{
    echo "OKAY";
}
else
{
    echo "NOT SO OKAY";
}
?>
```

To prevent the rest of the world from uploading files to my server, I will send a MD5-Hash key with the request and basically just wrap an "if($key == $serverkey)" around the code.

So it should look like this:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['key'] == $serverkey)
{
    $uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
    {
        echo "OKAY";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "NOT SO OKAY";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "WRONG KEY";
}
?>
```

My problem is now...how can I append the key to the request in the correct way, so I can access "$_POST['key']" as well as the file afterwards?
I don't want the key accidently applied to the file data.

The file is appended with the following code in Qt:

```
data.append(QString("--" + bound + "\r\n").toLatin1());
data.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + url + "\"\r\n\r\n");
data.append(scriptName + "\r\n");
data.append("--" + bound + "\r\n");
data.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + inputName + "\"; filename=\"" + inf.fileName() + "\"\r\n");
data.append("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) return;
data.append(file.readAll());
data.append("\r\n");
data.append("--" + bound + "--\r\n");
```

Is the file allready limited to the boundary?

Would PHP know the difference between the two if I just append another line like this:

```
data.append("&key=" + key);
```

Do I need the "&"?
I can't find anything on google to that...there are either strictly file uploads or some values like the key send via POST, but never both in the same request.
Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Since you're checking `$_POST` you have to add an additional POST-Parameter in your request. I think, you could also check `$_GET` in your PHP-Script and append `?key=md5stuff` to your URL.

Comment: That's even easier and works, thanks for the hint. You want to post that as an answer? Seems like I've made the most complicated approach again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, my comment as an answer.

Since you're checking `$_POST` you have to add an additional POST-Parameter in your request. I think, you could also check `$_GET` in your PHP-Script and append `?key=md5stuff` to your URL.